# Any good Ruby console application gems out there?

Tags: ruby, user-interface, console, rubygems

I'm digging around trying to find a good set of tools for creating console applications, as most of the settings I expect to be using Ruby in the coming months won't be webapps, but server-side scripts.

I know of [highline](http://highline.rubyforge.org/), and I do plan on using that for user and possible password prompts, but I know that the Console application world should be chock-full of other gems to assist and/or enrich your plain 'ol command-line apps.

Does anyone have some good suggestions?  I'm not exactly sure what I'm really looking for, but I wouldn't be surprised if there were gems in Ruby to help with **colorizing**, **ascii-like art**, **user-interaction** (similar to bash-completion), **man-page** similar tools (or generators) or just helpers for making the work of creating a richer console app not come across as being so difficult to understand, or plain and cryptic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's some console related gems I've written you may like:

- [bond](http://tagaholic.me/bond/) - Custom readline autocompletion of methods, arguments and more.
- [hirb](http://tagaholic.me/hirb/) - Framework for formatting ruby objects. Comes with tables, trees, selection menus and a smart pager.
- [alias](http://tagaholic.me/alias/) - Creates, manages and saves aliases for class methods, instance methods, constants, delegated methods.

Answer (score 1):

My table_print gem lets you see IRB output in easy-to-scan table format. Super simple, lightweight, customizable. http://tableprintgem.com

Comment: The link is broken for me. :(